# How can I call TX Timestamp info via Web3.JS

Tags: web3js, timestamp

How can I call the timestamp information of the pending tx datas I tried everything I could not.?

Comment: The timestamp belong to the block where the transactions are mined. If they were not mined they do not have a timestamp assigned yet.

Comment: if this information is not available, the geth node server sends past pending datas and ı cannot filter it with web3. for example when ı check etherscan some pending datas 1 day ago or 1 hours ago etc... show timestamp.. so ı don't want it.

Comment: The timestamp of transaction in the pending pool is not available in geth. It is likely Etherscan have a custom version that records such information.

Comment: So how can I prevent past pending data from coming in geth via Web3 method? I am using subscribe method

Comment: I don't know, you can always filter them yourself.